# create sql to return results per day

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a SQL that brings me a table with an aggregate SUM from the current month results.

```
SELECT VAR1
    ,VA2
    ,SUM(VAR3)
    ,SUM(VAR4)
FROM TABLE1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2
    ON TABLE1.VAR1 = TABLE2.VAR1
WHERE TABLE1.DATE >= '06/01/2017'
    AND TABLE1.DATE <= 'TODAY'
GROUP BY 1
    ,2
ORDER BY 2
```

However I need to return a table where it gives me day by day results instead.

How is it possible to construct with SQL. Maybe using a While ?

Appreciate any help on this matter

Thanks

Comment: add table1.date to your group by and cast it to a date if it's a datetime datatype.

Comment: How do you want to handle missing days?  For example, if `TABLE1` has no records for June 2nd and June 18th?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast your date field as a date to eliminate any time portions (if needed) and add it to the select (so you know what day is which) and group by (so the sum is by day).

```
SELECT VAR1
     , VA2
     , SUM(VAR3)
     , SUM(VAR4)
     , Cast(TABLE1.DATE as date)
FROM TABLE1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2
  ON TABLE1.VAR1 = TABLE2.VAR1
WHERE TABLE1.DATE >= '06/01/2017'
  AND TABLE1.DATE <= 'TODAY'
GROUP BY VAR1
       , VAR2
       , Cast(TABLE1.DATE as date)
ORDER BY VAR2
```

Also it's generally considered bad practice to use the column position in a group by/order by so I updated to the appropriate column names.

It looks like date may be a [reserved word](https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/iso-9075-sql-standard-keywords-reserved-words/); so if it really is the column name, you may need to escape it with double quotes, change the name: but note if you have to use double quotes, the column name becomes case sensitive.  If it's not too late it may be better to call it Event_Date, Start_date, End_date something more descriptive than just the data type.

Lastly, you're month sum is only based on the fact you're doing >= start of month.  If today becomes 8/1 then you have multiple months.  Do you really just need current months data?

Boa sorte!

Comment: Thank you XQbert. Based on your response I could find the solution. Obrigado !

Answer (score 1):

Adding Firebird specifics, you may use the [`EXTRACT` function](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-functions-datetime.html#fblangref40-scalarfuncs-extract).

```sql
SELECT 
  ....
GROUP BY
  Extract( YEAR FROM TABLE1.DATE ), Extract( YEARDAY FROM TABLE1.DATE ),
  VAR1, VAR2
```

Note, however, that this tends to have natural scan through all the table and then to externally sort all the raw data selected. It would potentially consume a lot of disk throughput, disk space and CPU time.

If you really have to do such queries often, then you better create special aggregates-accumulating table, where you would keep all the per-day sums and adjust them as they are changing.